# Webgl context is null if 2d context is called on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I wrote the following JS code:

```
var main=function() {
  var CANVAS=document.getElementById("your_canvas");
  CANVAS.width=window.innerWidth;
  CANVAS.height=window.innerHeight;
  //ctx=CANVAS.getContext("2d");
  //ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);

  /*========================= GET WEBGL CONTEXT ========================= */
  var GL;
  try {
    GL = CANVAS.getContext("experimental-webgl", {antialias: true});
  } catch (e) {
    alert("You are not webgl compatible :(") ;
    return false;
  }

  var CUBE_VERTEX= GL.createBuffer ();

};
```

If I uncomment the two commented lines, then the webgl context is NULL. Is this expected ? It's not possible to use 2D context and webgl context on the same canvas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, as webgl basically is a wrapper around opengl, primarily used for accelerated 3D rendering. `getContext("experimental-webgl")` is essentially telling the browser, that the defined canvas is to be used exclusively by OpenGL/WebGL. (It is possible to use OpenGL/WebGL for 2D, but unless you know what you are doing, you're giving yourself a hard time in doing so.)
If you are trying to render text on top of a 3D view, you will have to overlay two different DOM-elements (or render the text with the correct projection in 3D, again hard time-territory).

Comment: Ok it makes sense. Thank you !